# Function is Measurable if and only if the restricted function is Measurable

Tags: real-analysis

Let $g:E\to \mathbb {R}$ be a function on a measurable set $E$ and let $\{E_n : n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ be a family of measurable subsets of $E$ such that $E=\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$. Prove that $f$ is measurable on $E$ if and only if the restricted function $f\vert_{E_n}$ is measurable on $E_n$ for every $n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Only if:** If $f$ is measurable, then for each $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $f^{-1}((a,+\infty))$ is measurable. As each $E_n$ is measurable, we see that $f^{-1}((a,+\infty))\cap E_n$ is measurable. Notice that $f_{E_n}^{-1}((a, +\infty))=f^{-1}((a,+\infty))\cap E_n$, and we are done for this direction.

**If:** For each $a\in\mathbb{R}$, note that 
$$f^{-1}((a,+\infty))=f^{-1}((a,+\infty))\cap E=f^{-1}((a,+\infty))\cap\bigg(\bigcup_{n} E_n\bigg)=\bigcup_n [E_n\cap f^{-1}((a, +\infty))].$$
Because $f_{E_n}^{-1}((a, +\infty))=f^{-1}((a,+\infty))\cap E_n$, while we know that each $f_{E_n}^{-1}((a, +\infty))$ is measurable, we must have
$$f^{-1}((a,+\infty))=\bigcup_n [E_n\cap f^{-1}((a, +\infty))]$$
is measurable, since it is a countable union of measurable sets. This completes our proof.